# When to use K-Medoids instead of K-means

Tags: clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning, k-medoids

When it's better to use K-Medoids rather than K-Means? Can anybody give some examples of dataset for the same?

Comment: From Wikipedia: `It is more robust to noise and outliers as compared to k-means because it minimizes a sum of pairwise dissimilarities instead of a sum of squared Euclidean distances.`

Comment: You may also want to use K-medoid when you want the representers of the classes  to be one of the points in your dataset. Ex : representer of a class of pictures of faces is a blurry picture for K-means and it is a real picture of someone's face in K-medoid, one of the exemples of the dataset.

Comment: The question is similar to when to use median instead of mean. Check the answers here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6913/is-median-fairer-than-mean Mean is trying to minimize L2 loss and Median is trying to minimize L1 loss. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34613/l1-regression-estimates-median-whereas-l2-regression-estimates-mean/34615#34615